# PostgreSQL indices- are these redundant?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

```
CREATE INDEX alias_pub_idx2
  ON info.palias
  USING btree
  (publisher_id, player_id, pub_player_id);

CREATE INDEX alias_pub_idx3
  ON info.palias
  USING btree
  (player_id);
```

The first includes the three columns; the latter includes only the one. I'm thinking they are redundant- that the first btree index is sufficient, but I'm not terribly familiar w/ the PostgreSQL indexing methods. Thoughts?

Comment: Is that valid?  Last I heard, PostgreSQL didn't support covering indexes, which is what the `alias_pub_idx2` is.

Comment: That's what I initially thought, OMG - but they're not covering indexes - info.palias must be schema.table syntax.

Comment: Yes, sorry, info.palias is schema.table..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PostgreSQL multicolumn indexes are "ordered", which means this would be redundant only if `player_id` was the first column mentioned in `alias_pub_idx2`.

This, however, would be redundant :

```
CREATE INDEX alias_pub_idx2
  ON info.palias
  USING btree
  (publisher_id, player_id, pub_player_id);

CREATE INDEX alias_pub_idx3
  ON info.palias
  USING btree
  (publisher_id); /* first column of another index => waste of space */
```

Comment: So it right to say that if player_id is the column more joined on (by far), it should either be the first column in the index, or have its own standalone index?

Comment: @Wells yes, that's right. From the documentation: " the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns"

Answer (score 0):

Neither index makes the other redundant - a query against info.palias that looks for particular player_ids would favour the second index over the first if publisher_id is not also a criteria.

Answer (score 0):

> USING btree

[BTREE indexes are ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree), that's why your second index is redundant: The first column is the same and can be used in all queries where player_id is a condition.